# How does a photon released from particle A interacting with particle B, entangle them?

Tags: quantum-entanglement

What does a photon carry from its parent particle that when it interacts with another particle, it entangles both the particles?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "entanglement"  A photon carries energy/momentum and spin orientation. It can transfer this information to a particle it interacts witth, and the state of the second particle can give information about the state and energy level of the parent particle, for example.

Comment: @annav suppose the entanglement found between the two particles after one shared photon with the other is spin-entanglement.

Comment: why don't you read this question and answers https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/457922/ .

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the photon needs to be entangled with the particle that emitted it. That is not difficult to accomplish. One can for instance use the conservation of momentum to obtain an entangled state:
$$ |\psi\rangle = \sum_n |\mathbf{p}_n\rangle_{phot} |\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{p}_n\rangle _A\alpha_n , $$
where $\sum_n |\alpha_n|^2 = 1$ and $\mathbf{p}$ is the combined momentum of both particle A and the photon. When the photon now interacts with particle B, it will transfer an amount of momentum that is correlated with that of particle A. Hence, the two particles become entangled.

Comment: You appear to be talking about conservation of momentum.

Comment: Yes, conservation of momentum is one of the ways one can get entanglement

Comment: What's "spooky" about that?

Comment: What do you mean? Why does it have to be spooky? Please explain in a clearly phrased question what you have a problem with.

Comment: As I recall, Einstein referred to entanglement as spooky action at a distance.

Comment: No that is not the same thing. Einstein's spooky action at a distance, refer to nonlocal interactions, which are in contradiction with special relativity. Entanglement does not involve nonlocal interactions.

Comment: Separated by distance, does the change in momentum of particle A result in change momentum of particle B.

Comment: No, it does not work like that. One cannot affect the one particle by doing something to the other particle.