# How does a photon released from particle A interacting with particle B, entangle them both?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

What does a photon carry from its parent particle that when it interacts with another particle, it entangles both the particles?

Comment: Same question but no answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/463222/200082

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that particle A emits a photon that may be polarized either vertically V or horizontally H.  Particle A will react to that emission in either of two different ways, call them Av or Ah.  The photon can be absorbed by particle B, resulting in particle B ending up in either of two states , Bv or Bh.

Since the state of the photon's polarization is indeterminate, the states [A, polarization, B] are all linked together: either they are [Av,V,Bv], or they are [Ah,H,Bh].  We can't know which until we measure A or B, but we know that if we know the state of A we can reliably predict the state of B, and vice versa.

That is an adequate non-mathematical definition of entanglement between A and B.  You asked what the photon carries from A to B.  If it can be said to carry anything, you might say it carries "indeterminacy"; but in fact A, the photon, and B all share the same indeterminacy.

Comment: What happens in the case if particle A changes it spin and emits a photon and the photon absorbed by particle B? Is the photon enough that it can cause changes in particle B and entangles both particle?

Comment: Yes. That is correct.  A photon can be emitted by particle A and absorbed by particle B, resulting in entanglement of B with A.